# Webkit (Chrome/Safari) does not update display when custom attribute selected is changed

Tags: html, css

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/JVVcA/

### HTML:

```
<fieldset id="data-page">
    <legend>data-page</legend>
    <button rel="page1">Highlight page one</button>
    <button rel="page2">Highlight page two</button>
    <div data-page="page1">
        <h1 id="page1">Page one</h1>
        <h1 id="page2">Page two</h1>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="class">
    <legend>class</legend>
    <button rel="page3">Highlight page three</button>
    <button rel="page4">Highlight page four</button>
    <div class="page3">
        <h1 id="page3">Page three</h1>
        <h1 id="page4">Page four</h1>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

### CSS:

```
fieldset { border: 1px solid #aaa; padding: 5px; }

h1 { background-color: white; }
div[data-page="page1"] h1#page1 { background-color: pink; }
div[data-page="page2"] h1#page2 { background-color: pink; }
div.page3 h1#page3 { background-color: cyan; }
div.page4 h1#page4 { background-color: cyan; }
```

### JS:

```
$('#data-page button').click(function(){
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
    $(this).siblings("div").attr('data-page', rel);
});

$('#class button').click(function(){
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
    $(this).siblings("div").attr('class', rel);
});
```

### Initial load:

[image]

### After clicking "Highlight page two" and "Highlight page four" in Webkit (specifically, Google Chrome stable Windows 7):

[image]

### After doing the same in Firefox:

[image]

As you can see, the `data-page` selector works fine on the initial rendering of the of the page, but when the DOM is manipulated on the fly, styles defined by the `[data-page="???"]` CSS selector are not affected accordingly. Compare this to the situation with the class selectors. When classes are changed on the fly, the styles change as expected.

A possibly related note is that I've encountered cases while using this attribute selector in conjunction with CSS transitions where a similar lack of responsiveness happens, but on those cases, clicking elsewhere on the page, waving your mouse around, or just waiting for a bit eventually results in the expected change going through.

So is there a way around this other than to just throw up your hands and not use `data-page`-style attributes?

Comment: As a side-note, your jsFiddle does work correctly in Chrome dev.

Comment: It works on Chrome 14.0.835.163 m on Windows XP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the same issue that's applied for the `~` or multiple `+` selectors and pseudo-classes in webkit: this kind of selectors are rendered only once and the last time I checked the relevant bug reports in webkit's tracker, they stated that it works like *intended*.

But, some people had [found the fix](http://css-tricks.com/8439-webkit-sibling-bug/), but it's really is overhead: to add always-reflowing property to body, so it's must be added only to those elements, where something changes, the divs inside field sets for your example.

So, there is a fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JVVcA/2/

And these are the styles for fixing such problems:

```
/* The `fixing` animation */
@-webkit-keyframes bugfix { from { padding: 0; } to { padding: 0; } }
.anElementToFix { -webkit-animation: bugfix infinite 1s; }
```

Note that you must add the fix to the element whose attribute is can be changed, not the *targeted* by selector elements.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. One would wonder why, if this "works as intended", the same issue didn't occur in Windows versions of Chrome. In the meantime, I feel that perhaps this is a good time to throw in the towel on semanticity and go with the more efficient solution of using classes.

Answer (score 0):

My version of workaround.

```
$('#data-page button').click(function(){
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
    var my_div = $(this).siblings("div");
    my_div.attr('data-page', rel);
    var my_html = my_div.html();
    my_div.html(my_html);
});

$('#class button').click(function(){
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
    $(this).siblings("div").attr('class', rel);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Running an animation seems overly expensive.

Thanks to Zoltan Olah, I found a much more elegant, concise, and efficient workaround.

Simple toggle a nonsense class on the body. This will cause contained selectors to be re-evaluated.

You don't even have to define this class in CSS. Just applying it forces Safari to hunt through the page re-evaluating things.

Every time you change the attribute in question, toggle this class on or off to force the re-evaluation.

```
// change some attribute
$(".blah").attr("state", "otherState");   // example of changing an attribute (your app will be different)
$('body').toggleClass('zoltan');    // THIS IS THE LINE YOU MUST ADD EVERY TIME YOU CHANGE THE ATTRIBUTE
```

Comment: comment on the downvote would be sweet. ugly workaround, I know, but it's a small ugly workaround with a controllable cost.